# stuck writing recursive function that prints to the screen

Tags: c, design-patterns, recursion

I need to write a function that prints to the screen.  If the input is 5, then the output is:

```
+**
****
*******
***********
****************
```

This is my current code:

```
int recursions(int number,int condition)
{
    if(condition < 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("**");
        recursions(number + 2,condition - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Please give a number!\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("+");
    recursions(number,number);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I just want to ask some question.

Is it possible for a recursion to have

If ... elseIf .... else inside it?

Comment: Recursion needs an if, that way you know the function can terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int n){
    if(n > 0){
        putchar('*');
        print(n-1);
    } else
        putchar('\n');
}

void recursions(int n,int cond){
    if(cond > 0){
        print(n*(n-1)/2 + 1);
        recursions(n+1, cond-1);
    }
}

int main(){
    int number;
    printf("Please give a number!\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("+");
    recursions(2,number);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in `python`, you can easily translate it to `C`:

```
$ python3
>>> def fun(n):
...     if n==1:
...         print('+**')
...         return 2
...     else:
...         m = fun(n-1)
...         print('*' * (n+m))
...         return n+m
...
>>> fun(5)
+**
****
*******
***********
****************
16
```

Comment: just a quick question.

printf('*' * (n+ m))

is that "**" ?

Comment: in `python`: **`'X' * 5 ==> 'XXXXX'`**

Comment: in `C`: you can use a **`for`** loop.

Comment: How do you translate that into C, I never encountered that and what is it called?

Comment: I am only allowed recursions.

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos: what kind of `recursion` do you want?

Comment: Like a conditional recursion that I am used to.

That involves two parameters. One the number to me get created one and the second is the stop the program.

Comment: So, I am going to put a loop inside a recursion?